# Could a multi-camera SLAM system that is accurate at low driving speeds be equally accurate at high driving speeds?

Tags: computer-vision, robots, slam

Could a multi-camera SLAM system for self-driving cars that is accurate to [under 10 cm (3.9 in)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.09839.pdf) at parking lot speeds (i.e. very low driving speeds) retain this level of accuracy at high driving speeds (e.g. highway speeds or city driving speeds) if the cameras were **a)** 60 fps and **b)** had a global shutter?

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be accurate at higher speeds, if the processing system that processes the information from the camera system can process the information in real time. It looks like it can, but you will also have to account for motion blur. If there is too much motion blur, you will probably not be able to do anything other than speeding up the camera and processing system. However, if the motion blur is not that bad, and the system has been trained on the motion blur, it should be able to classify everything correctly.